# using onclick to change the price in a div

Tags: css, html, onclick

I have 2 images, When I click on one of these images I want the price to show I have treid the following:

```
<td style="padding-top: 2px; text-align: center" onclick="document.getElementById('price').firstChild.nodeValue=this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-price')"></td>

<img src="images/4.png" width="39" height="33" data-price="£245.00">
<img src="images/n4s.png" width="39" height="33" data-price="£255.00">

<div id="price"> </div>
```

Comment: Why did you choose onChange when it is onclick you want? could you also create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showprice1(){
    var price_div = document.getElementById("price")
    var price1 = document.getElementById("img1")
    price_div.innerHTML = price1.getAttribute('data-price');
}
function showprice2(){
    var price_div = document.getElementById("price")
    var price2 = document.getElementById("img2")
    price_div.innerHTML = price2.getAttribute('data-price');
}
</script>

<img src="images/4.png" id="img1" onclick="showprice1();" width="39" height="33" data-price="£245.00">
<img src="images/n4s.png" id="img2" onclick="showprice2();" width="39" height="33" data-price="£255.00">

<div id="price" style="padding-bottom:10px"></div>​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fxUpM/

Comment: perfect thanks. Also is it possible to change the picture once clicked on?

Comment: Also is it possible to change the picture once clicked on?

Comment: @user1667346 yes, just add code to the functions, this should work: `document.getElementById("img1").src="image_url_here.png"`

Comment: thank you. Thanks in this div is also a buy it now button. I have created 2 separate paypal buttons for each price. paypal button: http://jsfiddle.net/69yTQ/. Both buttons are exactly the same but each have a different 'value'. how can i change the 'value' depending on which image the user selects?

Answer (score 1):

It's similar approach like @heidi answer, but more simpler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showprice(e){
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = e.getAttribute('data-price');
    }
</script>

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JnUKx.jpg" id="img1" onclick="showprice(this);" width="39" height="33" data-price="245.00">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/c8Rwp.gif" id="img2" onclick="showprice(this);" width="39" height="33" data-price="255.00">

    <div id="price" style="padding-bottom:10px"></div>​
```

You can check this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxUpM/1/).

You can use jQuery here, instead pure javascript. It will make much easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks in this div is also a buy it now button. I have created 2 separate paypal buttons for each price. paypal button: http://jsfiddle.net/69yTQ/. Both buttons are exactly the same but each have a different 'value'. how can i change the 'value' depending on which image the user selects?